# Probleme in recursion JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm a beginner in JavaScript and would like to know what is the point of assign `countdown(n - 1)` to `countArray` and why we don't use `push()` instead of `unshift () explanation`, please

```js
function countdown(n){
  if (n < 1) {
    return [];
  } else {
    var countArray=countdown(n - 1);
    countArray.unshift(n);
    return countArray;
  }
}

console.log(countdown(5)); // [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation on [`unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) vs. [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here you give a number like 5, so it will create an array with reverse order like [5,4,3,2,1].

Unshift is basically to put the element at the first of the array

Let us go by one by one step

first it will check 5<1, no so it goes to else condition and creates a function call with countdown(4),

so like wise it will create function stack till 1 countdown(1) because when it reaches 0 it will return an empty array since if condition matches

so then it will resolve from top of the stacktrace,

stacktrace will be

- countdown(1)
- countdown(2)
- countdown(3)
- countdown(4)
- countdown(5)

so the empty array has been returned to that empty array countdown(1) will execute and unshift to the first position

now array will be [1]

next it will execute the countdown(2) and unshift means to the first index it will add so the 1 gets moved to the second position

now array will be  [2,1]

like wise

it reaches countdown(5)

and array will be [5,4,3,2,1]

thats it

Answer (score 0):

`countdown(n - 1)` calls the countdown function with the value of `n`decremented by one. So for example, your if first call is `countdown(5)`, when the line `countdown(n - 1)` is encountered, countdown is called with the value 4 - (countdown(4)).

This continues until the value of n is less than 0 which is when an empty array is returned from the function.

`unshift` removes a value from the array while `push` adds onto an array. This code gradually empties the array and that is why unshift is used.

Comment: can u explain to me what this line do :            " var countArray=countdown(n - 1);"

Comment: It assigns the result of calling `countdown(n - 1)` to a variable called `countArray`